# Appending to a vector with push_back as opposed to [ ]

Tags: string, c++11, vector

Part of a program I was working with needed to append string values to a vector. I reached a segmentation fault when appended the string values like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < testvec.size(); i++) {
    testvec[i] = oldvec[i];
}
```

But my program compiled and executed correctly with this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < testvec.size(); i++) {
    testvec.push_back(i);
}
```

This is the gist of it, what we were doing was updating a vector

Comment: The second loop either doesn't do anything (if `testvec.size() == 0`) or doesn't terminate until the program eventually runs out of memory (otherwise). The first loop is OK (but doesn't actually append anything) as long as `oldvec.size() >= testvec.size()`, and exhibits undefined behavior otherwise. In any case, it's not clear to me what exactly either piece of code is supposed to achieve.

Comment: To append the contents of one vector at the end of another vector, write `testvec.insert(testvec.end(), oldvec.begin(), oldvec.end());`. No loop necessary.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` indexes into *already existing* space in a `vector`. Say your vector was default constructed:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
```

Then doing `v[i]` for any `i` is undefined behaviour, as there is no guarantee that any space has yet been allocated to store values. It's effectively equivalent to:

```
std::string *storage;
storage[i] = "...";
```

Your code still looks incorrect: I'm guessing it's actually something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < oldvec.size(); i++) {
    testvec.push_back(oldvec[i]);
}
```

This is the long way of going about it: to construct a vector that has the elements contained in another vector, the simplest way is:

```
std::vector<std::string> testvec(oldvec.begin(), oldvec.end());
```

Comment: I actually edited my post, and I think your answer is directed to the question prior to the edit. My code actually compiles with push_back and not the operator[].

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> testvec(oldvec);` is even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

`push_back()` is the correct way to append items to a vector. It will reallocate the underlaying memory block as needed to fit the new items. `operator[]` however, does not grow the vector, so it can only insert new items if the vector was previously resized with `resize()` or by inserting with `push_back()`. If you try to use `operator[]` without doing so, it will result in undefined behavior.